# Addon: Render burst - doesn't work as expected

Tags: rendering, add-on, camera

It should do a Render batch for selected cameras, but it just keeps repeating the same camera and I can't cancel it. I have to kill it with task manager.
 [Video:](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/f6f70b/render_burst_doesnt_work_need_help/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an issue with an addon and should be reported to the author

Comment: Shameless self promotion: Even better use my fork from [here](https://github.com/p2or/RenderBurst/tree/Cleanups), submitted a [patch long time ago](https://github.com/VertStretch/RenderBurst/pull/12) which fixes a lot of their code related issues, adds it properly to the menu bar and has a closed panel by default ;)

Comment: @p2or Such self-promotion is very appreciated :). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the newest version with 2.81+ compatibility.
It's available here on [GitHub](https://github.com/VertStretch/RenderBurst), and [here's a cleaned-up version](https://github.com/p2or/RenderBurst/tree/Cleanups) by @p2or.

Don't forget to enable it in *Preferences > Addons*

[image]